# How to read the Headers and Response from the SAML Response in Java using Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-security, single-sign-on, spring-saml

I'm working with SSO authentication using Spring SAML Security. I'm totally new to this concept. 
I  have configured the Spring SAML configuration, and my iDP is from another server which i access using metadata url, once the authentication is successfull i need to read the SAML Response Headers and based on that i need to build a string.

I can able to login and I'm able to see the SAML Response using a chrome tool.

Here is my code to implement spring saml

```
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Value("${security.saml2.metadata-url}")
String metadataUrl;

@Value("${server.ssl.entity-id}")
String entityId;

@Value("${server.ssl.key-alias}")
String keyAlias;

@Value("${server.ssl.key-store-password}")
String password;

@Value("${server.port}")
String port;

@Value("${server.ssl.key-store}")
Resource  keyStore;

@Value("${server.ssl.key-store}")
String  keyStoreAlias;

@Value("${server.ssl.postLogoutURL}")
String postLogoutURL;

@Value("${server.ssl.appId}")
String appId;

@Value("${server.ssl.key-alias}")
String alias;





@Override
protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/saml*").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
        .apply(saml())
            .serviceProvider()
                .keyStore()
                    .storeFilePath(this.keyStoreAlias)
                    .password(this.password)
                    .keyname(this.keyAlias)
                    .keyPassword(this.password)
                    .and()
                .protocol("https")
                .hostname(String.format("%s:%s", "localhost", this.port))
                .basePath("/")
                .and()
            .identityProvider()
            .metadataFilePath(this.metadataUrl);
}
```

So how to capture the SAML response in spring saml here.

Thank you